# Semantic question about Pressure in fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

[image]

I have a semantic question about [Bernoulli's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Incompressible_flow_equation),

I learned that Bernoulli's equation is: $$\frac{v^2}{2} + \frac{P}{\rho} +gy=const.$$

My question is why is it that at point $C$ the pressure is $$P_o - \rho gh $$ and not $$P_o + \rho gh ?$$
what is the meaning of the minus sign?

Consider $y=0$ as drawn in the picture.

Comment: Please explain your setup. from the pic it is unclear where we have a fluid.

Comment: the fluid is in the floor lvl, which marked $y=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fluid is flowing from the pipe at point C, the pressure is Po.  If the pipe is closed at point C, the pressure is Po + ρg(H + h).

Comment: The fluid is flowing from point $C$ but this point is located at $y= -h$ so how can the pressure there be just $P_o$?